# Hugo theme within another theme

Tags: themes, hugo

My question is as follows -

I have a website A for which I am using a Hugo theme, say Theme A. I have another website B, for which I would like to use Hugo Theme B. My problem is that website A is the main website and I would like to add website B to website A, but website B should retain the Hugo theme B. Additionally, Hugo Theme B should behave as a sub-theme of Hugo Theme A meaning Hugo Theme B should use the masthead and footer of Theme A. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the concept of theme families. Theme A will be the master theme, and you could design the theme B as a child theme of theme A.

Here is the official documentation about this:
https://gohugo.io/hugo-modules/theme-components/

Here is a discussion about the concept of sub themes
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/sub-themes-or-theme-families/3938

For the implementation, it depends of:

- where are hosted websites A and B (together in the same hugo site or in different site)
- if you need to share data between both or just the theme